# Extension shortcuts in Google Chrome don't have text in them, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have a few extensions next to my URL bar in Chrome on Windows 7. When I press any of them, or even the bookmark star, the text box that pops up is clear.

I am using the following extensions: Adblock plus, Google Translate, Firebug Lite, Ghostery, Avast Web Rep, Ultimate UserAgent switcher, Web developer toolbar, desprotetor de links, DNT plus, and WOT.

I am set to block popups but not javascript in Chrome and have a blackout theme installed.
Any ideas?

Comment: try changing the theme?

Comment: yeah after i typed that out i just started changing each individual thing. It was the theme that was causing this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions are unlikely to cause such incidents, the theme might be at culprit and might have caused the text colour to be something which cannot be seen clearly.

Change the theme and it should be fine